# I'm using selenium to extract the text "Option C" . Using browser.find_element_by_class_name('color'), the output was "Answer :", how to get it?

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

```
  <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
  <div class="page-content">
  <div class="boxedtitle page-title">
  <h2 class="t_left">Answer & Solution</h2>
  </div>
  <div><span class="color">Answer:</span><strong> Option C</strong> 
  </div>
```

So here I want to extract the text "Option C", how to get this with selenium ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [find_element_by_css_selector](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_element_by_css_selector-driver-method-selenium-python/) driver method and select the `strong` element using the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `+`.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.color + strong');
```